# How to create reusable footers in SSRS 2008?

Tags: ssrs-2008, footer, reusability

In my project I am already having a number of reports and also new reports are being created. Now I need to apply a common Footer (with page number, total page number, user name, report name and execution time) for all these reports. This footer has to be in such as way that we can modify it anytime (at a single place) and all the reports will get modified footer there after. Also the footer should be re-usable.

I have tried out approaches like 
1) Creating a report and putting it inside the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject - This allows the reusablility of the template. But if modified will not get applied to existing reports.

2) Creating sub-report and adding it to the end of the Data area in main report. This provides re-usablility as well as modifiable features. But not able to show Page Number, Total Page Numbers etc... and also not able to show the footer in each page of the report.

Can anyone give me some leads on how these features can be acheived?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. Templating seems to be one of the main deficiencies of SSRS.

It's not ideal, but what you could possibly do is create an xsl stylesheet to process all of your RDL files and add/ update the footers.